# How to pass one RDD in another RDD through .map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two rdd's, and I want to do some computation on RDD2 items for each item of rdd1. So, I am passing RDD2 in a user defined function as below but I am getting error like `rdd1 cannot be passed in another rdd`. Can I know how to achieve this if I want to perform operations on two rdd's?

For example:

`RDD1.map(line =>function(line,RDD2))`

Answer (score 4):

Nesting RDDs is not supported by Spark, as the error says. Usually you have to go around it by redesigning your algorithm.

How to do it depends on an actual use case, what does exactly happen in `function` and what is it's output.

Sometimes a `RDD1.cartesian(RDD2)`, doing operations per tuple and then reducing by key will work. Sometimes, if you have `(K,V)` type a join between both RDD will work.

If RDD2 is small you can always collect it in the driver, make it a broadcast variable and use that variable in `function` instead of `RDD2`.

@Edit:

For example's sake let's assume your RDDs hold strings and `function` would count how many times a given record from `RDD` occurs in `RDD2`:

```
def function(line: String, rdd: RDD[String]): (String, Int) = {
   (line, rdd.filter(_ == line).count)
}
```

This would return an `RDD[(String, Int)]`.

**Idea1**

You can try using a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) using RDD's `cartesian` method.

```
val cartesianProduct = RDD1.cartesian(RDD2) // creates RDD[(String, String)]
                           .map( (r1,r2) => (r1, function2) ) // creates RDD[(String, Int)]
                           .reduceByKey( (c1,c2) => c1 + c2 ) // final RDD[(String, Int)]
```

Here `function2` takes `r1` and `r2` (which are strings) and returns `1` if they are equal and `0` if not. The final map would result in an `RDD` which would have tuples where the key would be a record from `r1` and value would be the total count.

Problem1: This would NOT work if you have duplicate strings in `RDD1`, though. You'd have to think about it. If `RDD1` records have some unique ids that would be perfect.

Problem2: this does create A LOT of pairs (for 1mln records in both RDD it would create around 500bln pairs), would be slow and most probably result in a lot of [shuffling](http://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/).

**Idea2**

I didn't understand your comment regarding RDD2's size `lacs` so this might or might not work:

```
val rdd2array = sc.broadcast(RDD2.collect())
val result = RDD1.map(line => function(line, rdd2array))
```

Problem: this might blow up your memory. `collect()` is called on the `driver` and `all` records from `rdd2` will be loaded into memory on the driver node.

**Idea3**

Depending on the use case there are other ways to overcome this, for instance [brute force algorithm for Similarity Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_search) is similar (pun not intended) to your use case. One of alternative solutions for this is [Locality Sensitive Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have use case like in One RDD i have millions of rows and more than 200 columns and in another rdd i have lacs of records and columns. I need to take every row from RDD1 and need to do some comparison and computation on entire RDD2.To achieve this I am thinking to pass this RDD2 in RDD1.But if we cant support nested RDD in spark  then how to overcome this issue.

Comment: @RaghavendraKulkarni expanded my answer with an example

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk, "lac" == 100,000 (used in India).

Comment: Thank you so much Mateusz Dymczyk

Comment: @RaghavendraKulkarni no problem. Did it solve your problem? If yes it would be cool should you accept this as the answer. If not we can think about something different if you provide more details :-)

Comment: Thanks MateuszDymczyk , somehow I worked by collecting the dataframe/RDD then I am passing in the function.But I dont think that collect is a good approach to invoke before calling the .map since RDD is big so its taking much time before passing into the function.Can we declare RDD as global so we can use it in function?